# Good covering of a sphere

Tags: linear-algebra, mg.metric-geometry, it.information-theory

Consider a sphere $S_r(0)$ with center at zero and radius $r$ in the Hamming space $\{0,1\}^n$.
We will be interested in covering this sphere with balls of radius $\rho  < r$.

We know that there is an optimal covering, i.e. a covering such that $S_r(0) \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^{i=k} B_{\rho}(x_i)$ and $|B_r| \cdot Poly(n)\ge k \cdot |B_{\rho}|$.

In analogy with the paper ["Good coverings of Hamming spaces with spheres"](http://www.renyi.hu/~pfrankl/j29.pdf) by Cohen and Frankl (published in Discrete Mathematics, North-Holland, 56 (1985), pages 125-131), let us call a covering *good* if the set $X$ consisting of the centers of the covering balls satisfies $X = S_r(0) \cap L$, where $L$ is some linear subspace of $\{0,1\}^n$.

**Question:** Is there a good optimal covering of $S_r(0)$?

Comment: Is $S_r(x)=\{u \in \{0,1\}^n: d(x,u)=r\}$?

Comment: @kodlu, yes it is

Comment: Does linear optimal mean as good as any (without linear restriction)?

Comment: Linear over $\mathbb{F}_2$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov yes, I mean $\mathbb{F}_2$

Comment: @FedorPetrov But If it can be done for something another structure, then it will be interesting too

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński yes